# how to refresh ng-include on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I would like to load and pass parameters to a ng-include.

and when the user clicks on a button, it would like to reload the same ng-include with another parameter.

it's not working now. any idea how to make this work ?

here is the code : [http://plnkr.co/edit/marR00jw2k2EU2Rp3QR6](http://plnkr.co/edit/marR00jw2k2EU2Rp3QR6?p=preview)

html :

```
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="loadList(A)">A</button>
    <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="loadList(B)">B</button>
    <div ng-include="'tplList.html'" onload="loadList(0)"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.services', 'myApp.controllers']);

angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']).
    factory('List0', function($resource){
    return $resource('list0.json');
    }).
    factory('List1', function($resource){
        return $resource('list1.json');
    }).
    factory('List2', function($resource){
        return $resource('list2.json');
    });

angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'List1', 'List2', function($scope, List1, List2) {
    $scope.loadList = function (param) {
        if (param === 'A') { 
            $scope.elms = List1.query(); 
        } else if (param === 'B') {
            $scope.elms = List2.query(); 
        } else {
            $scope.elms = List0.query();
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, you need to pass `A`, `B` as string like this

```
<button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="loadList('A')">load list 1</button>
<button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="loadList('B')">load list 2</button>
```